# Python matplotlib superscript offset too high above text

Tags: python, matplotlib, superscript

I have superscripted the '3' in the label shown below. I am unhappy with the height of the superscript.

[image]

This is the code I used to make the axis label: `ax2.set_xlabel('$\\rm{\gamma}$$_{total}$ (kN/m$^3$)')`

Is there a way to alter the subscript offset so that the '3' is lower, closer to the 'm' character?

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The superscript is "outside" as if it were operating over the whole unit.

Go from

```
ax2.set_xlabel('$\rm{\gamma}$$_{total}$ (kN/m^3$)')
```

to a single "Latex" expression

```
ax2.set_xlabel('$\rm{\gamma}_{total}\,(kN/m^3)$')
```

Probably the units will not have the font you want, but I'm sure you know how to fix that ;)

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense and worked as:  '$\\rm{\gamma}_{total} (kN/m^3)$'.  Thanks!